# RecyclerView adapter doesn't update data with databinding

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-databinding

Please help me with a problem.
I have activity.xml file with recyclerView which I set an adapter like:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
          android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="@color/white"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:visibility="@{viewModel.recyclerVisibility}"
          app:adapter="@{viewModel.adapter}"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/title" />
```

So I set the adapter here in xml but it is not updating after I receive data from server in my viewModel:

```
someObservable.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe {
     adapter.setItems(it)
     notifyPropertyChanged(BR.adapter)
})
```

To bind adapter in xml and have an access to it I have the method in my viewModel like:

```
@Bindable
fun getAdapter(): SomeAdapter {
    if (adapter == null) {
        adapter = SomeAdapter(emptyList())
    }
    return adapter as SomeAdapter
}
```

And in my adapter I have method to update datalist:

```
fun setItems(someData: List<SomeData>) {
    this.someData = someData
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

So what the problem here? because I see the empty adapter on UI so I guess the binding doesn't work fine..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a silly but not obvious mistake but the problem is solved :)
I forgot to add layout manager for my recyclerView like:

```
app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
```

in xml or you can do it programmatically..
**it happens :)